# How to assign materials to multiple material slots of an object?

Tags: python, mesh, materials

`object_A` has 4 materials slots already in use by different materials (`mat_x`, `mat_y`, `mat_z`, `mat_w`).

4 materials: `mat_1`, `mat_2`, `mat_3`, `mat_4`

How can I assign 4 materials to `object_A` while keeping the same materials slot number (my existing materials on `object_A` have already been assigned to specific faces)?

This is my main code block:

```
for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    mat = mesh_dic.get(mesh.name)
    if mat:
        mesh.materials.clear()
        mesh.materials.append(mat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace all the materials with `new_materials`, keeping the slots and their mesh selection.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


new_materials = [
    bpy.data.materials['mat_1'],
    bpy.data.materials['mat_2'],
    bpy.data.materials['mat_3'],
    bpy.data.materials['mat_4'],
]


for material in context.object.data.materials:
    index = context.object.data.materials.find(material.name)
    context.object.data.materials[index] = new_materials[index]
```